# JRuby: cannot convert instance of class org.jruby.RubyObject to class java.time.Instant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I'm developing on a Ruby on rails (Rails 3.2.22.4) application. Ruby is JRuby (jruby1.7.x).

### Problem

I'm calling a RESTful Java service from this rails application. The request of calling java service contains `java.time.Instant`, I tried to use ruby `Time`, `DateTime`, and use `java_import` directly to create java.time.Instant, but none of them worked. I got

> TypeError: cannot convert instance of class org.jruby.RubyObject to class java.time.Instant

### Question

Is there any ruby class, or other work around I should use to address this type conversion problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate "calling a java service", is that like SOAP? Anyway, when interacting with java objects directly, this might help: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/GeneratingJavaClasses

Comment: It's a RESTful Java service. Updated in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JRuby 9.2 supports these by default when doing `Time/DateTime#to_java`

so when JRuby's Java Integration sees a `java.time.Instant` parameter it will auto-convert a Ruby `Time` (or `DateTime`) object.

for (old) JRuby 1.7 this obviously won't work, but creating a `java.time.Instant` type directly really should have worked, so keep looking into that. its hard to tell what failure are you having with that.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I think I might have messed up with something else. Tried to do it from scratch again and use `java.time.Instant`, it worked.